# Omitting an implied article, or avoiding repetition

Tags: articles, zero-article

If I say "The boy and girl are..."

I think it's as correct as "The boy and the girl", as some natives told me that.

Do you confirm?

But **what is the rule in English for non repeating the article**?

And also, more generally, are there other rules for omitting the *singular* article? When could it be *implied*? (I don't mean the zero article, like in generalities, categories and plural, when we expect the zero article.)

Comment: (1) Possible duplicate of [Can articles be omitted in front of the second and third nouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270511/can-articles-be-omitted-in-front-of-the-second-and-third-nouns) //// (2, 3, 4....) Omission of an article before a single noun is a wide topic; examples are needed. There are [almost 90 questions tagged 'zero article'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zero-article), many obviously asking 'Why is no article used in this case...?'

Comment: Thank you for having helped me without downvoting, it's the first time I see nice people here!

Comment: Hello, Quidam. While regulars on ELU appreciate good questions (they're what keep the site going) and are delighted to offer such help as they/we can, the right to indicate that certain questions or answers are not suitable (eg because they would be better asked on say ELL as being more basic, because they've been asked before on ELU, because they lack signs of reasonable research or because they're off-topic) is considered proper and essential in an attempt to maintain standards. Are the police not nice because they maintain standards in the ways laid down in the rules?