# Definite article "the" multiple times

Tags: definite-articles

We have this phrase that aims to communicate that after an organization is selected, the table is shown but also the button as well.

> The table and button are shown after an organization is selected.

Wouldn't it sound better to include "the" like:

> The table and the button are shown after an organization is selected.

Is there a rule or something to generalize its correct use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can articles be omitted in front of the second and third nouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270511/can-articles-be-omitted-in-front-of-the-second-and-third-nouns)

Comment: It's entirely your choice. You could also use this: ***Both*** *the table and button are shown after an organization is selected.*

Comment: @jimm101 well those answers conflict with each other, should I conclude that there isn't a consensus or rule about this?

Comment: @Jason "Both the table and the button" is fine. But, if you want to express that meaning, "Both the table and button" is not OK. The words "both" & "and" indicate a structure "Both N1 and N2", which walls the word "the" into N1 and prevents that "the" applying to N2.

Comment: Answers on StackExchange sites often will. The votes give guidance on the opinions in the community as to the right answer. If there are contradictions there, then yes, it's likely there is no definitive, agreed upon answer. The term "close" here doesn't remove your question, it just points people back to a question addressing the same topic, and keeps a single point of reference for answers, rather than have it spill into two places.

Comment: @RosieF If I write *Jane ate the fish and chips*, you'd assume I was talking about a single food item. If I write *Jane ate **both** the fish and chips*, you'd assume one of two things: she ate two orders of the single food item, or she ate two separate food items.

Comment: Duplicate question: [Is it necessary to use "the" multiple times?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9487/is-it-necessary-to-use-the-multiple-times) Here, 'correctness' is merely style preference; I'd use a second 'the' in this case because I consider the table and button to be best considered as being distinct, and articles 'package', compartmentalise (rather than bundle) conveniently.

Answer (score 0):

Repeating 'the' is not necessary most of the time, just as in this case.

It is entirely your choice, though I like to see it as I do contractions because for me it feels more clear and formal when you repeat it just as when you write for example "I am" instead of "I'm"

You may find this to be useful as well: [Is it necessary to use "the" multiple times?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9487/is-it-necessary-to-use-the-multiple-times)