# Are you supposed to repeat "the" when two "the" nouns are used in conjunction?

Tags: grammar, articles

Is "the red and blue", where each is a separate noun, grammatically correct? Or should it be "the red and the blue"?
(Note: they are separate nouns because the context makes it clear they are specifically the red and (the) blue of a particular object, this is implied) (This is a random example)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can articles be omitted in front of the second and third nouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270511/can-articles-be-omitted-in-front-of-the-second-and-third-nouns)

Comment: To a certain extent it's a question of emphasis.

Comment: "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly" ... Do you think it would be just as impactful with only one "the"?